# DataDescription contains no data after data is retrieved from CRM using SavedQueryVisualization

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I retrieve data from CRM online using the following code line. This code retrieves a single-series chart.

```
SavedQueryVisualization query= (SavedQueryVisualization)_orgService.Retrieve(SavedQueryVisualization.EntityLogicalName, guid, new ColumnSet(true));
```

After running this line, *query.PresentationDescription* has the following data:

```xml
<Chart Palette=\"None\" PaletteCustomColors=\"91,151,213; 237,125,49; 160,116,166; 255,192,0; 68,114,196; 112,173,71; 37,94,145; 158,72,14; 117,55,125; 153,115,0; 38,68,120; 67,104,43; 124,175,221; 241,151,90; 186,144,192; 255,205,51; 105,142,208; 140,193,104; 50,125,194; 210,96,18; 150,83,159; 204,154,0; 51,90,161; 90,138,57;\">
<Series><Series ChartType=\"Column\" IsValueShownAsLabel=\"True\" Font=\"{0}, 9.5px\" LabelForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" CustomProperties=\"PointWidth=0.75, MaxPixelPointWidth=40\"></Series></Series>
<ChartAreas><ChartArea BorderColor=\"White\" BorderDashStyle=\"Solid\"><AxisY LabelAutoFitMinFontSize=\"8\" TitleForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" TitleFont=\"{0}, 10.5px\" LineColor=\"165, 172, 181\" IntervalAutoMode=\"VariableCount\"><MajorGrid LineColor=\"239, 242, 246\" /><MajorTickMark LineColor=\"165, 172, 181\" /><LabelStyle Font=\"{0}, 10.5px\" ForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" /></AxisY><AxisX LabelAutoFitMinFontSize=\"8\" TitleForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" TitleFont=\"{0}, 10.5px\" LineColor=\"165, 172, 181\" IntervalAutoMode=\"VariableCount\"><MajorTickMark LineColor=\"165, 172, 181\" /><MajorGrid LineColor=\"Transparent\" /><LabelStyle Font=\"{0}, 10.5px\" ForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" /></AxisX></ChartArea></ChartAreas>
<Titles><Title Alignment=\"TopLeft\" DockingOffset=\"-3\" Font=\"{0}, 13px\" ForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\"></Title></Titles>
<Legends><Legend Alignment=\"Center\" LegendStyle=\"Table\" Docking=\"right\" IsEquallySpacedItems=\"True\" Font=\"{0}, 11px\" ShadowColor=\"0, 0, 0, 0\" ForeColor=\"59, 59, 59\" /></Legends></Chart>
```

However, query.DataDescription is the following:

```xml
<datadefinition>
  <fetchcollection>
    <fetch mapping=\"logical\" aggregate=\"true\">
      <entity name=\"invoice\">
        <attribute groupby=\"true\" alias=\"_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0\" dategrouping=\"month\" name=\"datedelivered\" />
        <attribute alias=\"_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0\" name=\"totalamount\" aggregate=\"sum\" />
      </entity>
    </fetch>
  </fetchcollection>
  <categorycollection>
    <category alias=\"_CRMAutoGen_groupby_column_Num_0\">
      <measurecollection><measure alias=\"_CRMAutoGen_aggregate_column_Num_0\">
      </measurecollection>
    </category>
  </categorycollection>
</datadefinition>
```

I was expecting to have series and category values present in DataDescription but they are not there. How can I get series and category values of the chart retrieved?